# Can I find blocking sessions within a specific time period in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I searched across this portal for my query but I always got solution of blocking sessions for the active session.
So here is my scenario, where I need to visit my last weeks blocking sessions.
Can someone pls help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you licensed to use AWR/ ASH?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to both, can u pls help?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to edit the timings on this query but maybe this is what you are looking for -

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.sql_id,
                a.inst_id,
                a.blocking_session         blocker_ses,
                a.blocking_session_serial# blocker_ser,
                a.user_id,
                s.sql_text,
                a.module,
                a.sample_time
  FROM GV$ACTIVE_SESSION_HISTORY a, gv$sql s
 WHERE     a.sql_id = s.sql_id
       AND blocking_session IS NOT NULL
       AND a.user_id <> 0                                  -- exclude SYS user
       AND a.sample_time BETWEEN SYSDATE - 1 AND SYSDATE - 23 / 24
```